# Firebase firestore query for two inputs integer/string

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get data from firestore based on 2 fields (localitate:string, buget:integer).

The query is getting pretty verbose and still doesn't work as expected..

```
function get_collection(){

    let ref = firebase.firestore()
    
    if (store.form_data.optiune === "camera") {
        ref = ref.collection("listing")
    } else if (store.form_data.optiune === "coleg") {
        ref = ref.collection("user")
    }
    return ref
}


function build_query(){
    
    let ref = get_collection()

    let localitate = store.form_data.localitate
    let buget      = Number(store.form_data.buget)
    
    // Build query
    if (localitate && buget){   
        console.info("Filtru localitate && buget: ", localitate, buget)
        ref = ref.where("localitate", "in", [localitate]).where("buget", "<=", buget)         
    }
    else if (localitate){
        console.info("Filtru localitate: ", localitate)
        ref = ref.where("localitate", "in", [localitate])                  
    }
    else if (buget){
        console.info("Filtru buget: ", buget)
        ref = ref.where("buget", "<=", buget)
    }

    // Add limit of items
    if (store.last_ref === undefined) {
        ref = ref.limit(items_per_page)
    } 

    console.info("Last ref is ", store.last_ref)
        
    if (localitate && store.last_ref !== undefined) {
        
        ref = ref.orderBy(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId())
            .startAfter(store.last_ref)
            .limit(items_per_page)    
    } 
    else if (buget && store.last_ref !== undefined) {
        ref = ref.orderBy("buget")
                .startAfter(store.last_ref)
                .limit(items_per_page)   
    }

    return ref
}
```

How to keep the limit of items got on each `get()` and also add proper filter functionality to "listing" and "coleg" collections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order by budget and change it from "<=" to ">="

```
function build_query(){
    
    let ref = get_collection()

    let localitate = store.form_data.localitate
    let buget      = Number(store.form_data.buget)

    console.info("Filters: ", localitate, buget)
    
    // Build query
    if (localitate && buget){   
        console.info("Filtru localitate && buget: ", localitate, buget)
        ref = ref.where("localitate", "in", [localitate]).where("buget", ">=", buget)         
    }
    else if (localitate){
        console.info("Filtru localitate: ", localitate)
        ref = ref.where("localitate", "in", [localitate])                  
    }
    else if (buget){
        console.info("Filtru buget: ", buget)
        ref = ref.where("buget", ">=", buget)
    }

    // Add limit of items
    if (store.last_ref === undefined) {
        ref = ref.limit(items_per_page)
    } 

    if (buget && store.last_ref !== undefined) {
        console.info("Sort by buget", buget, store.last_ref)
        ref = ref.orderBy("buget")
            .startAfter(store.last_ref)
            .limit(items_per_page)
    }

    else if (store.last_ref !== undefined) {
        console.info("Sort by id", store.last_ref)
        ref = ref.orderBy(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId())
            .startAfter(store.last_ref)
            .limit(items_per_page)    
    }
        
    console.info("Last ref is ", store.last_ref)

    return ref
}
```